# Is an iframe for a HIPAA-compliant form still HIPAA-compliant if the iframe is used on a non-HIPAA-compliant website?

Tags: html, forms, iframe, privacy, hipaa

Do externally-hosted forms in `<iframe>` tags pass any data through the internal server that is using the iframe?

**For more context if my question isn't clear:**

Assume I'm a healthcare provider using Jotform for lead-gen forms.
Assume I'm on their HIPAA-compliant plan complete with a BAA signed. And I've created a form that can be embedded or used in an iframe.
Assume I'm using Wordpress for my website and my Wordpress server is not HIPAA-compliant because it doesn't need to be—no PII of any kind passes through the servers whatsoever other than the standard IP addresses in logs.

If I use an iframe on my non-HIPAA-compliant Wordpress site to show a Jotform-hosted HIPAA-compliant form, is there any way the data input into the form would pass through the Wordpress server?

I've tried only using links directly to jotform in a new window, but have not tried "embedding" using an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe will run completely independently of your WordPress server, WordPress will never be able to see any of the data entered into the form.